# Function overloading fail when call it in member function with same name

Tags: c++, overloading, member-functions

As title, when I called a function in definition of a member function with same name. I got compile error `no matching function for call to 'test::print(int&)'`

Does this mean function overloading by different arguments can't work in member function?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class test{
    public:
        void print();
};

void print(int n);

int main(){
    test t;
    t.print();
    return 0;
}

void test::print()
{
    for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
        print(i);
}

void print(int n){
    cout << n;
}
```

Comment: [this is not the code for the error message you report](https://ideone.com/ELby0p)

Comment: @user463035818 I fixed the missing `{` so the code gives the actual error now.